# procedure to run apex program in Eclipse IDE

Tags: ide, eclipse

I am new in SFDC, I just download Eclipse IDE and wrote a sample code of apex class. 
Now I am not getting option from where I have to run this class.
thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should be using the [Force.com IDE](https://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE) which Salesforce provides for developers.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to call the code, as opposed to integrate it somewhere else in Salesforce?

If so, and it has a public constructor and method, you can call it from anonymous apex. There are instructions for using the Execute Anonymous view in the [Introduction to the Force.com IDE](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Force_IDE).

[image: Eclipse Anonymous Apex]

There are lots of other ways to execute apex code. It depends on what your code is doing and how you intend to use it. E.g. Triggers, web services, controllers for Visualforce pages, test cases, batch classes, ...